# How to keep mouse over object when using drag and snap to with d3.js

Tags: d3.js, drag-and-drop

I have created a simple fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/oqu8j072/

The code is:

```
function onDragDrop(dragHandler, dropHandler) {
  var drag = d3.behavior.drag();
  drag.on("drag", dragHandler).on("dragstart", startHandler).on("dragend", dropHandler);
  return drag;
}
function startHandler() {
  d3.select(this).style('cursor', 'move');
}
function dropHandler(d) {
  //Finished
}
function dragmove(d) {
  d.x += Math.round(d3.event.dx / 10) * 10;
  d.y += Math.round(d3.event.dy / 10) * 10;
  //d.x += d3.event.dx;
  //d.y += d3.event.dy;
  d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")");
}
var DrawCircle = function(container) {
  var d = [{ x: 50, y: 50 }];
  var circle = container.data(d).append("g").attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; }).call(onDragDrop(dragmove, dropHandler));
  circle.append("ellipse").attr("cx", 20).attr("cy", 20).attr("rx", 20).attr("ry", 20).attr("stroke", "#FF0000").attr("stroke-width", 1).attr("fill", "#FF0000");
}
d3.selectAll("svg").remove();
var svgContainer = d3.select("#MainDiv").append("svg").attr("width", 800).attr("height", 600).attr("version", 1.1).attr("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg").attr("viewBox", "-40, -40, 1600, 1200");
DrawCircle(svgContainer);
```

On dragmove I use:

```
d.x += Math.round(d3.event.dx / 10) * 10;
d.y += Math.round(d3.event.dy / 10) * 10;
```

To make the circle snap to every 10 units of the viewbox.

If I use the commented code:

```
d.x += d3.event.dx;
d.y += d3.event.dy;
```

Then the circle is moved as expected, but when I use the code to make it move 10 units at a time the mouse cursor starts moving further and further away from the object.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is disassociating the mouse from the circle.  It's working against the "difference" is position instead of the absolute position.

Try:

```
function dragmove(d) {
    d.x += d3.event.dx;
    d.y += d3.event.dy;
    movex = Math.round(d.x / 50) * 50;
    movey = Math.round(d.y / 50) * 50;
    d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate(" + movex + "," + movey + ")");
}
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oqu8j072/1/).

Comment: Thanks Mark. I have a second part to this. I don't know if it's warranted to start a new question. I have modified your fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/oqu8j072/2/ This highlights a new problem, there is a label that shows the co-ords of the circle, if you drag the circle, move the cursor off the circle then hover back over, you can see that the X, Y co-ords don't match the snap points.

Comment: Doh! I guess the obvious answer is that everytime I want to use the value then I round it off. Like this (for those that may have the same problem): http://jsfiddle.net/oqu8j072/3/

Comment: @Family, After some thought, I don't like my answer.  With my solution `d.x` and `d.y` no longer reflect the true position of the circle.  While it can be made to work, it's not quite kosher.  Try this one:  http://jsfiddle.net/oqu8j072/4/

Comment: This is a nice solution. Thank you.